# In Core Data, is it a good practice to have an one-to-one relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm having two entities: A and B in Core Data. A has an one-to-one relationship to B. Will I be better off to just save an entityB'Id in entity A, then do a fetch on entity B whenever I need?

My thoughts:

I still think having one-to-one relationship is better.

1. I agree that having a one-to-one relationship sometimes is not necessary.But I checked the sqlite file Core Data generated. To me, it looks like core data is saving that relationship as a column with an Id inside it. So I don't think saving an one-to-one relationship is more expensive than saving an entityB' Id.
2. After I fetch an object from entity A, having a one-to-one relationship allows me to access the related object in entity B without fetching again. And I think it's better to do one fetch to get an object with a relationship than do two fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is probably fine.  I agree that there is no real performance hit but storing the data in a relationship; faulting a relationship is very fast.  If the data in the relationship is relatively large it can be a good practice to store it in a separate entity as that allows it to not be faulted when not needed.  Storing it in one entity can make some interactions with a fetchedResultsController easier.  For example if are fetching entity A but have a predicate that is based party on entity B, if entity B changes the fetchedResultsController will miss it.